# How to mark entity property default value to null if column not exist in spring jpa

Tags: java, database, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have met a situation that my entity may related to the tables which has different columns.
For example, my entity has 2 properties(A and B). Related tables may have two versions, one table has A column only and the other table has A and B columns.
So if using entity in one column table, it will raise exception about the property B

I try to use `@Transient` to mark B properties. It does not meet exception in one column situation. But in two columns table, the column B's information is missing since I omit B properties.

So, I expected when in one column table, the B properties can be set as null. Also in the two columns table, the B properties value can be caught from DB.

I try to use the `@MappedSuperclass` to create a base abstract class and create a class extends base class. But no matter where I put B properties, in base class or extended class. Or no matter which I use findAll() method or use @Query(native sql query) to query, it still raise the same exception as before.

When using findAll():
ERROR: column table.B does not exist

When using @Query(native sql query):
The column name B was not found in this ResultSet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA - Optional columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098541/jpa-optional-columns)

Comment: If I correctly understand: You map one entity to two different tables? That's not possible with JPA.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, actually there is one table. But with different version, version 2 has one more column. So the entity has the same property numbers as version 2. But in some situation, the new entity will be used with version 1 table, and we can't change version 1's structure. So we need a method to make new entity also run in version 1 situation.

Comment: @Akirus, thank you. I have done some try and updated the result in description part. Seems it not work...

Comment: That's not possible.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, ok...maybe I need to rethink another solution. Thank you for your help.